# django how to prefetch with an Integer?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

models

```
class Challenge(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    version = models.IntegerField(...)

class Workout(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    version = models.IntegerField(...) # this field may not exist

# this is a through table
class ChallengeWorkoutRelation(models.Model):
    challenge_id = models.IntegerField() # for some reason, this is IntegerField, not ForeignKey
    workout_id = models.IntegerField() # for some reason, this is IntegerField, not ForeignKey
    version = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to get all workouts belong to one challenge:

```
for relation in ChallengeWorkoutRelation.objects.filter(challenge_id=challenge.pk, version=challenge.version):
    workout = Workout.objects.get(id=relation.workout_id)
    # do something with workout...
    
    # another version
    # workout = Workout.objects.get(id=relation.workout_id, version=challenge.version)
```

Can I optimize this code to get more performance?

Comment: What is the reason it is an `IntegerField`? I don't follow why you want to use an `IntegerField`?

Comment: Because this database is read-only(not managed by me), id cannot determine the unique record (the id will be repeated). just like composite primary key(version + id). Maybe I should use Subquery?

Answer (score 0):

yess, you can optimize the code to improve performance by reducing the number of database queries. The key is to minimize the number of times you hit the database. In your code, you are currently doing a separate database query for each Workout related to the Challenge, which can lead to a large number of database queries.

You can use the select_related or prefetch_related queryset methods to retrieve related objects along with the ChallengeWorkoutRelation query in a more efficient way. In your case, since ChallengeWorkoutRelation has foreign keys to both Challenge and Workout, you can use select_related to fetch related Workout objects along with ChallengeWorkoutRelation in a single query.

Here's an optimized version using select_related:

```
relations =
ChallengeWorkoutRelation.objects.filter(challenge_id=challenge.pk,
version=challenge.version).select_related('workout')

for relation in relations:
    workout = relation.workout
    # do something with workout...
```

This way, you're fetching all related Workout objects in a single query rather than making a separate query for each relation.

Alternatively, if you have a large number of relations, you might want to consider using prefetch_related:

```
relations =
ChallengeWorkoutRelation.objects.filter(challenge_id=challenge.pk,
version=challenge.version).prefetch_related('workout')

for relation in relations:
    workout = relation.workout
    # do something with workout...
```

prefetch_related is more suitable when dealing with reverse foreign key relationships or when you have a larger number of related objects.

Choose between select_related and prefetch_related based on your specific use case and performance testing.